# write csv to external file

Tags: python, python-2.7

It seemed that I do not understand how csv.write works. Any hint will be very helpful.

When I write:

```
x=['1468853914','2016-07-18 12:04:56.2 UTC', '0','970.157']
import csv
myFile = open('csvexample4.csv', 'w')  
writer = csv.writer(myFile, delimiter=',')
writer.writerows(x)
```

I expect to get a comma delimited csv file with one line as follows

```
'1468853914','2016-07-18 12:04:56.2 UTC', '0','970.157'
```

but I get

```
 1,4,6,8,8,5,3,9,1,4
 2,0,1,6,-,0,7,-,1,8, ,1,2,:,0,4,:,5,6,.,2, ,U,T,C
 0
 9,7,0,.,1,5,7
```

Comment: Don't forget to do `myFile.close()`

Comment: writer.writerows() assumes that you have an iterable representing numerous rows, so it's treating each of your list elements as a single row and assuming that the list items are iterables that it joins with `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `writerow`

**Ex:**

```
x=['1468853914','2016-07-18 12:04:56.2 UTC', '0','970.157']
import csv
myFile = open(filename, 'w')  
writer = csv.writer(myFile, delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(x)
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow)**